# C++ command pattern with large number of params

Tags: c++11

I am implementing a command pattern implementations with large number of actions and parameters involved. To simplify I am planning to use class that can hold all possible params to module in a map.

```
class ParamBag {
public:
    add(int paramId, shared_ptr<IParam> param);
    bool contains(int paramId);
    std::shared_ptr<IParam> get(paramId);

private:
    int mask;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<IParam>> params;
};
```

One clear downside of this implementation is each param has to extend from IParam interface, can I somehow simplify this.

Comment: This is easy to mitigate with `template<class Param> class ParamWrapper: public IParam{...}` (or `std::any` or `variant`). I'm not sure this simplifies anything though. A struct holding all parameters as members is not more complicated.

Comment: I would have used a struct but at any given point of time to support a command 20 - 30 % of superset params will be used. ParamBag approach can hold all (superset) / subset of params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the one that uses the param after the get knows the type of the param, then you can use c++17 `std::any`, or if you must use c++11 you can try `boost::any`, or if none of those you can resort back to a `void*`.

The difference is that void* will not fail on a cast to a wrong type, where `any_cast` would throw an exception, or return nullptr if used with a pointer. You would also need to use a custom deleter in the std::shared_ptr in order to be able to free the void*.

Comment: I ended up using templates as suggested by @n.m